# How to change a google map into something similar to the poster background?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

[image]

[image]

How do I change a google map into something similar to the map in the 1st poster?
How do I change it to blue and also include shadows?

Please help!

Regards,
sammydude

Comment: Are you asking how to turn any map into black and white and overlay on blue? Or are you asking how to make a Google Map look like a turn-of-the-century engraving?

Comment: I want to make a Google Map look like a turn-of-the-century engraving. Probably after that I could overlay the image with blue to resemble something similar to the above image.

Comment: Well, there's no magic step to do that. There are some fairly nice engraving plug-ins for Photoshop that MIGHT get you close, though.

Comment: But note in your example that that *is* an old engraving. It would have been hand illustrated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do these steps in Photoshop:

- Find a texture for map/paper that suits your need. In my example I am using the following texture:
  http://i.istockimg.com/file_thumbview_approve/2205516/2/stock-photo-2205516-ancient-map-texture.jpg

These has a license that can be purchased if you need to use it commercially.

- In Photoshop, load the map and texture into two different layers and use Multiply on the top layer:

[image: Multiply layers]

That will give you something like this:

[image: Map flattened]

At this stage you might want to consider extending/cloning edges and so forth depending on the usage.

- Flatten the two layers and convert the image into a "3D Postcard" (Photoshop CS5+ extended):

[image: 3D Postcard menu]

- Rotate as needed (use the *camera* rotate tool).
- Then add a spot-light to the scene, place it where you need it and set colors for scene and the light.
- You want to turn down ambient light pretty much almost to the bottom. Also give it a blue hue:

[image: Ambient lighting]

- Then set the light color - also adjust hotspot, softness and intensity to achieve best results.

[image: Light color]

This will result in something like this - not identical, but to show the steps in one approach to achieve this type of look:

[image: Final result]

Answer (score 2):

Stamen Maps looks like a great resource for changing the styling of maps.

http://maps.stamen.com

Comment: That page is amazing! Perhaps it'd be good to add an explanation of what it does or a couple of images of the results, so the answer gives a better idea of it before clicking the link.